# Find SPUser Preferred Name from UserPrincipal

Tags: 2010, active-directory, spuser

I am looping through a group of `UserPrincipal` that was retrieved from Active Directory. I need to get find a `SPUser` using the properties of the `UserPrincipal`. Once the `SPUser` is found I will get its `UserProfile["PreferredName"]`.

I have tried passing all of the following to `SPUser` and the exception says user not found:

1. `UserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName`
2. `UserPrincipal.DisplayName`

I should also mention the reason I need to find the Preferred Name is because the `UserPrincipal.DisplayName` that I will eventually pass to a People Picker is resolving as the Preferred Name which I am afraid will mess us up later. I have already synced the Preferred Names, there are just a couple that are stuck as 'domain/username' instead of 'firstname lastname'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD users don't exist on SharePoint until something causes SharePoint to know about them (e.g. an explicit permission setting, the user has logged in, etc).

Try using SPWeb.EnsureUser(string userlogonname) - it will create the user within SharePoint if it doesn't already exist, and return the SPUser object.